# Syncframework 2.1 handling InsertConflicts

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a application that uses Sync framework 2.1.

The data model:
[image]

When 2 clients insert a new row for example a new product and also makes a new order that contains the new product I receive a LocalInsertRemoteInsert message. When I handle this message, I gather the fields of the conflicted row and re insert this row to get a new ID.

For example:

Client 1 inserts product with ID 2 and an order with OrderID 1 that contains ProductID 2

Client 2 inserts product with ID 2 and an order with OrderID 1 that contains ProductID 2

After syncing, the tables are filled with both products and orders but…
The order of client2 has a foreign key to the product that client 1 made. Because the product of client 2 has a new ID (ID will be 3 in this case).

I tried to fix it with a GUID (uniqueidentifier) as ID’s but Syncframework doesn’t accept uniqueidentifier’s, I receive the error: “Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int”. when I try to define the scopes…

The code what I use to create the scopes:

```
 private void Define_Server(string tableName)
        {
            // define a new scope named ProductsScope
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(tableName+"Scope");

            // get the description of the Products table from SyncDB dtabase
            DbSyncTableDescription tableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, _serverConnection);

            // add the table description to the sync scope definition
            scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc);

            // create a server scope provisioning object based on the ProductScope
            SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(_serverConnection, scopeDesc);

            // skipping the creation of table since table already exists on server
            serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

            try
            {
                if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists(tableName + "Scope"))
                {
                    // start the provisioning process
                    serverProvision.Apply();
                    log.Info(String.Format("Succesfully provise the {0}Scope in the server", tableName));
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                log.Error(ex);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I have used Syncframework with GUIDs without problem, don't remember any limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Sync Framework works with GUIDs. Sync Framework however doesn't do schema syncs. and it wont update its metadata/objects as well when you modify the schema/data types.

If you changed the data type, just deprovision the database and reprovision and you should be good to go.